# How to read in a double from a file in c++

Tags: c++, file-io, input, double, inputstream

How do you read in a double from a file in C++?

For ints I know you can use the getline() and then atoi, but I am not finding an array to double function. What is available for reading in doubles, or converting a char array to a double?

Comment: why not read it in as a char* and use sscanf?

Comment: @incrediman: Because if you are already using the standard streams you probably don't want to be dealing with C function headaches.

Comment: If you want to insist on doing `getline()` and then `atoi()`, you could replace `atoi()` with `atof()` and you should be fine. But @R Samuel Klatchko's method should work fine for both doubles and ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use stream extraction:

```
std::ifstream ifs(...);
double d;
ifs >> d;
```

This work provided that other then whitespace, the next data in the stream should be a double in textual representation.

After the extraction, you can check the state of the stream to see if there were errors:

```
ifs >> d;
if (!ifs)
{
    // the double extraction failed
}
```

Comment: This is wrong.  Test the stream for failure (`.fail()`, which is subtly different than `.good()`, which is equivalent to `.rdstate() == 0`).  Use `if (!(ifs >> d)) {/*failed*/}` or `ifs >> d; if (!ifs) {/*..*/}` or (the generally more useful) `if (ifs >> d) {/*use d*/} else {/*failed*/}`.

Comment: (Using `!stream` is the same as `stream.fail()`, using `bool(stream)` is the same as `!stream.fail()`.)

Answer (score 3):

Do not consider using atof(), or any of the ato.. functions, as they do not allow you to diagnose errors. Take a look at [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/) and [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/). Or use the stream extraction operators.

Comment: @sblom Is it the grammar you object to? If so, please suggest improvements.

Comment: In other news, @Neil, I just noticed you're an "all time top c++ answerer" with accumulated 1337 answers! WIN!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%2b%2b&sort=stats&pagesize=15

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering, does one need to be careful about locale settings (e.g. a locale could use comma instead of dot to separate the decimal part) or do stringstreams always default to some standard "C locale" notation?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/) For example, here are toDouble and toInt:

```
double toDouble(string s) {
  double r = 0;
  istringstream ss(s);
  ss >> r;
  return r;
}

int toInt(string s) {
  int r=0;
  istringstream ss(s);
  ss >> r;
  return r;
}
```

Comment: This already exists in boost, in a much better form including error checking, as lexical_cast.

Comment: @Roger Pate: Yes, it does. This is useful though for cases where you can't use boost.

Comment: @Billy: It is no more useful than atof, which Neil correctly [points out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615078/how-to-read-in-a-double-from-a-file-in-c/2615119#2615119) should be avoided (unless you've already validated the input, but that's not true here).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: (@Billy: Since you got a mysterious downvote on your now-deleted answer, I feel compelled to say that wasn't me, nor have I downvoted any answer here for merely suggesting atof or omitting error handling.  I've been out of votes for the past 18 hours and have my next 30 already bookmarked for 0:01 GMT too. :P)

Comment: @Roger Pate: No problem. Reason I deleted it is because I considered your comment and I agree ;)